# Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log_Formatter_Simple' not found with Magento

Tags: magento

I get this error while trying to implement a block for a specific module. I put it with the stack trace :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log_Formatter_Simple' not found in /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/community/Bms/Recrutement/Block/Annonce.php on line 20

Call Stack:
0.0012     692544   1. {main}() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/index.php:0
5.0145    1334240   2. Mage::run() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/index.php:96
5.0351    3083736   3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/Mage.php:683
26.9640   17422296   4. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
26.9974   19462280   5. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:176
27.0049   20055160   6. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:250
27.4144   28301984   7. Bms_Recrutement_IndexController->annonceAction() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:419
27.4144   28301984   8. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/community/Bms/Recrutement/controllers/IndexController.php:30
27.7507   28773096   9. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:269
27.7509   28777880  10. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:344
27.9351   37337024  11. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:210
27.9351   37338856  12. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:205
27.9352   37341256  13. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:239
27.9352   37341256  14. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:472
27.9352   37341568  15. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:437
27.9356   37342840  16. Varien_Autoload->autoload() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:0
27.9369   37401728  17. mageCoreErrorHandler() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:98
27.9369   37402272  18. Mage::log() /users/christophe/dev/------/public/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:247
```

Here is the class I use :

```
class Bms_Recrutement_Block_Annonce extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    public function getUrl() {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        var_dump($data);
        return 'http://some_url';
    }
}
```

And finally the .phtml

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>" style="width:100%; height : 490px;"></iframe>
```

I do not have an idea where it can come from. If you have an answer or any hint, I will be glad to get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake !

getUrl() is already a function that is set in parent class and used elsewhere. I renamed it to getIframeUrl() and everything is ok.